# C++ When to delete object initialized with new if needed for return?

Tags: c++

I'm confused as to when I should be deallocating the following object from memory:

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
};
ListNode* addTwoNums(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2){
    ListNode *head = new ListNode(0);
    ...
    return head->next;
}
```

Since I'm returning the head object, when should I delete it such that I don't have a memory leak?

Comment: I'm confused by what this code is supposed to be doing. Why return a ListNode pointer? Why `head->next`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every function accepting or returning a pointer needs to have a contract regarding who is responsible for owning the resource pointed to by the pointer.  When you use raw pointers, such as you did, this contract is implicit, which means you'll need to figure out who frees the object (it seems obvious that the caller must).

If you read up on `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`, you'll find some very nice and useful alternate ways of expressing this contract, which will help you sidestep the question of who owns the object, and rely on the standard library to determine that.

Comment: I would hesitate to recommend `std:::shared_ptr` for returning from a function. If you return a `std::unique_ptr` then the caller can release it into a `std::shared_ptr` if they need that (which is less likely).

Comment: @Galik: `std::shared_ptr` allows to hide `Deleter`, which might be better for virtual functions for example (we might then provide noop deleter, or use aliasing `std::shared_ptr`). Also, some might argue the "optimization" of `std::make_shared` too.